# What does "Why is C++ used at all now that a faster language (Go) has been created?" really mean?

Tags: translation

It is translated into Chinese as "現在為什麼C ++使用了更快的語言（Go）？"。

For me, it seems not close. I feel its Chinese translation should be "現在有更快的語言 (Go)，為什麼還要用C++?"
Or, I feel in English, it's close to "Now, since there is faster language (Go)， why is C++ still used?"

Could anyone rewrite this sentence into simpler English or translate it into Chinese?

Comment: It's obvious that Google translation has still room to improve.

Comment: I don't know Chinese, and this question seems to relate to a translation into Chinese that wasn't good.  However, it isn't clear what the English question is.  You restructured the English version into an equivalent sentence, so you understand the meaning of the original sentence.  It seems like the question is how to translate an English sentence into Chinese, which isn't really on-topic.

Comment: This sentence of English is from Quora's question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the google "translate" translation into English from Chinese.

Comment: Is Go faster than C++...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about understanding an English sentence, not learning Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

as a native chinese,I prefere your translation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation seems fine. Here's my try at translating this sentence into Chinese:

> Why is C++ used at all now that a faster language (Go) has been created?
>
> 鉴于现在有更快的语言，为什么还要用C++?

The original English sentence should probably have been stated similarly to how we are translating this in Chinese, where we mention the Go programming language first:

> Now that we have a faster language (Go), why is C++ used at all?

This way the context of the question "why is C++ used at all?" is clearly given first.

Answer (score 1):

现在已经开发出了更快的语言Go, 为什么还要使用C++.

Because Go is not developed for system level usage, it is not supposed to replace C++.

Rust is the one. Use Rust.